# activerecord sum returns a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This seems very strange to me, an active record sum returns a string, not a number

```
basket_items.sum("price")
```

This seems to make it work, but i thought i may have missed something, as this seems like very strange behaviour.

```
basket_items.sum("price").to_i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7439

> There was a reason it returned a string - calling to_d on a Fixnum in Ruby 1.8 would give a NoMethodError. This is no longer the case in Ruby 1.9 so it's probably okay to change.

Answer (score 3):

According to the (rails 2.3.9) API:

> The value is returned with the same data type of the column, 0 if there’s no row

Could your `price` column be a `string` or `text`?

Comment: It is possible though that the database is sqlite3 in which case everything is stored as a string which might be causing the issue. I don't experience the problem on mysql but don't have sqlite3 to test against at the moment.

Comment: Using mysql, and my price column is a float, using Rails 2.3.9

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveRecord sum:**

Difference:

**1) basket_items.sum("price")**

It will also sum non integer also and it will return non integer type.

**2) basket_items.sum("price").to_i**

This above will convert into integer.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb, line 92
def sum(*args)
  if block_given?
    self.to_a.sum(*args) {|*block_args| yield(*block_args)}
  else
    calculate(:sum, *args)
  end
end
```

Calculates the sum of values on a given column. The value is returned with the same data type of the column, 0 if there’s no row.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

Github:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f8f4ac91203506c94d547ee0ef530bd60faf97ed/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L92

Also see, [Advanced sum() usage in Rails](http://functionalelegant.blogspot.in/2008/04/advanced-sum-usage-in-rails.html).